# How to get weighted mean with two weighting sources

Tags: weights, weighted-mean, weighted-data

I have some data on a cyclists distance traveled and hours it took.

```
    MILES  HOURS MPH    DAYS_AGO  WEIGHT
0   2      5     0.4    10        0.3175
1   5      10    0.5    4         0.3375
2   14     20    0.7    2         0.3450
```

I am trying to get an average of `MPH` for the cyclist.

The `WEIGHT` column in this table is using an exponential time decay to get the appropriate weight `0.99 ^ DAYS_AGO` so samples further back in time have smaller weights.

The issue I am stuck on is this becomes a weighted average since the `HOURS` per row differ but then there is an additional weighting source which is the exponential time decay.

Would something as simple as `sum(MILES * WEIGHTS)` / `sum(HOURS * WEIGHT)` work for this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your question, what is the problem of the traditional sum(weight*MPH)/sum(weight) ?

Comment: @PrestonLui the MPH's of each row have different amount of hours

Comment: 0.4 MPH in 5 hours (row 0) isn't the same as 0.7 MPH in 20 hours (row 2)

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question: exactly what *kind* of average do you want?  In settings like this, the *arithmetic mean* of the speed is equivalent to the *harmonic mean* of its reciprocal (time taken per unit distance)--and both can be relevant, depending on the application.

Comment: I would like the weighted arithmetic mean, which is `sum(miles) / sum(hours)` but I would like this to also be weighted by the WEIGHT column in this table which is an exponential time decay where it gives a higher weight to more recent observations @whuber

Comment: @radio23 So you also want to weigh the data by the hour? Then it indeed makes sense to calculate it using sum(MPH*(decay*hour))/(sum(decay*hour)) or to simplify sum(mile*decay)/(sum(hour*decay))

Comment: But the fundamental problem of comparing a short splint and a long run is great anyway. You kind of should categorize the data by, say, distance and/or time of completion anyway

Comment: Yes I want to weigh the data by the hour as well as the time decay so sum(miledecay) / (sum(hourdecay) is what I wanted to know if that makes sense, and I agree with categorizing the data but the data I have is different but this was the clearest example I could think of so I just wanted to make sure that sum(miledecay) / (sum(hourdecay) makes sense, thank you @PrestonLui

Comment: @radio23 there aren't really any weight that is unreasonable and as long as you can make a story, the prediction is good, the model is a good model